# ONE controller with TWO navigation bars

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using 2 `UINavigationController`s, all is fine, except that when I return to a previous controller in the other UINavigationController I have its navigation bar + the navigation bar of the previous controller, example:

```
Navigation Controller1 => A controller => B controller => Navigation Controller2=> C controller.
```

When I segue from C controller to A controller I have the navigation bar of both Navigation Controller1 and 2.
I tried to make that when I leave C controller:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
    NSLog(@"Disappeared!");
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

But I always have the same problem.
Any hints, ideas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you have two navigation controllers? You really shouldn't do. There's nothing that you can do with two nav controllers that you can't do with one.

Comment: I should because I'm using two sidebar menus, the library need a UINavigationController in every side bar menu.

Comment: Can you not use the same nav controller for both? Also, I'd discourage using one side menu never mind two. http://www.oliverfoggin.com/the-hamburger-menu-is-it-a-good-thing/

Comment: @Fogmeister: I tried to use the same navigation controller but that's impossible. And if I find something that can hold a list of more than 10 menu items I'll use it instead of the "hamburger menu". Tab bars can not have more than 5 (it'll be ugly then).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seriously doubting your need for two navigation controllers, but if you think you do, you can hide one controller's navigation bar by calling `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` on `self.navigationController` in the appropriate view controller.

Comment: if I hide navigation my navigation bar button is also get hidden

Answer (score 1):

Why are you pushing UINavigationControllers within each other? It's not a good iOS Programming practice. You can present second Nav Controller as `modal controller` on 1st Nav. controller, and dismiss it when you have done your task.

Comment: The problem is I MUST use navigation controller to create a side bar menu. Will try your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Oh right. You are putting it in viewDidDisappear though, which isn't called on a push to a new segue. Put it in viewWillAppear of the presented view controller.