# AutoLayout issue with TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have encountered a very awkward autolayout issue. I have a Navigation controller, i have set its rootviewcontroller as tabbarview controller for some purpose. See Image bellow:

[image]

In above image you can see there are 6 viewcontroller connected with tabbarviewcontroller.

- In 3rd 4th 5th and 6th viewcontroller a white view is added and autolayout as given below:

[image]

Now, after run when i select tab 3 or 4, the added view shows perfectly as i wanted and according to autolayout it should be show as it is showing. i.e given below: 
[image]
 [image]

Now when I select "more" then it showing a tableviewcontroller as it should be according to its default behaviour, is given below:

[image]

Here is the problem occurred, now if you select any item from the list and go to respected view controller, the white view added goes down from navigation bar. I don't understand why this happening. please see in the pic:

[image]
[image]

Whole day I had tried to fix this but nothing happens, some how got one solution but it was not what I needed here. i.e see Image below:

[image]

If uncheck "Under Top Bars" for that view controller then its works fine, but it affects the navigation bar, which I not wanted here. please see the image:

[image]

Can somebody here who had faced the similar kind of problem and found a perfect solution and I'm looking for help.

Note: No class have been taken in any view controller, all are in storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do disable **Adjust Scroll View Insets** of viewController.

Comment: @KKRocks did that, not working.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false in appdelegate try this

Comment: it does work but comes with a back button below the navigationbar. it is not what i looking for. @KKRocks

Comment: can you send screen shot this ?

Comment: @KKRocks Yes, here is the image: https://ibb.co/fpzg85

Comment: did you add second naviagation bar in this controller ?

Comment: @KKRocks No certainly not, i did as you said with UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false in appdelegate.

Comment: try to hide naviagation bar in ViewWillAppear for this contoller

Comment: @KKRocks well some how it is working, but having some issue to, like after adding  UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false, "more" option is appearing like this: https://ibb.co/doEngQ and when I hide the navigationbar in viewwillappear and come back to "more" again it showing like before: https://ibb.co/hRP3MQ which is not acceptable either :( .

Comment: This is the problem there is a two navigation bar....you can track view hierarchy.....can you explain me what you want ?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to upvote your answer for your thinking and pretty much you dig out the reason why it is happening. but i need to get ride of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem there is a two navigation bar....you can track view hierarchy.....can you explain me what you want ?

Comment: yes, some how I needed a single navigationbar with rootviewcontroller tabbarcontroller, now up if add 5 viewcontrollers in that tabbarcontroller and add a subview of view through the story board, it works fine for all 5 view controller, but as i add one more view controller, the 5th view controller and the 6th viewcontroller comes under a tableview, thats fine, but when i select that any viewcontroller from table view then the add subviews gows down. may it is happening what your answer, And i pretty much sure it does due to two navigation controller, but to get ride of it now..?

Comment: check you viewcontroller in storyboard....try to remove that navigation controller.

Comment: But i have to keep that for my real project.

Comment: what is real project...you need to remove for only this controller.

Comment: How could you remove that ?

Comment: select that navigation bar and press delete key or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549703/3901620

Comment: It helps me thanks, I found more relevant way I think, please see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Took a UiTbaBarControllerClass for my tabbarcontroller and in that that controller i set delegate self and follow my code, now its working as i wanted. very thanks to @KKRocks

**Code:**

```
 #import "TabBarController.h"

    @interface TabBarController ()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>

    @end

    @implementation TabBarController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.delegate = self;
    }

#pragma mark UITabBarController Delegate

    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
     didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
        NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);

        if ([viewController.title isEqual:@"More"]) {

           [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated: NO];
        }
    }
```

And in **Swift**:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.delegate = self
    }

// MARK: UITabBarController Delegate

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

        print("controller class: \(String(describing: viewController.self))")

        print("controller title: \(String(describing: viewController.title))")

        if viewController.title?.isEqual("More") {

            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now it working very fine. :)